# Bootstrap and FancyBox: Take the img ALT attribute and use it as a caption?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, fancybox-2

I'm using Bootstrap with the Fancybox plugin and trying to get a thumbnail ALT attribute and use it as a caption below the photo like so: [FancyBox demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2LXNh/)

However, taking that idea and implementing it with my Bootstrap demo gets the code working fine except that the ALT attribute is nowhere to be [seen in action](http://ogmda.com/3dms-public/gallery.php). Note: Only testing the first photo of my gallery at the moment.

My code:

```
<a class="thumbnail fancybox" rel="lightbox" href="http://placehold.it/400x400.png">
    <img class="img-responsive" alt="First title here" src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
    <div class="text-center">
        <small class="text-muted">Image Title</small>
    </div> <!-- text-center / end -->
</a>
```

The script at the bottom of my page is:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.fancybox').fancybox();
});
</script>

<script>

$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    beforeShow : function() {
        var alt = this.element.find('img').attr('alt');

        this.inner.find('img').attr('alt', alt);

        this.title = alt;
    }
});

</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have init fancybox 2 times, try just using the script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".fancybox").fancybox({
            beforeShow : function() {
                var alt = this.element.find('img').attr('alt');

                this.inner.find('img').attr('alt', alt);

                this.title = alt;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

REMOVE this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.fancybox').fancybox();
    });
</script>
```

---

PS: may be add document ready to the second fancybox init should work, but remove the unecessary code will be better

Comment: taht was the solution!